# Plotting confidence bands of a regression model with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot the 95% confidence bands for an exponential model with ggplot2. I use the following code for that

```
x <- seq(1,3,0.01)
y <- exp(x)+ rnorm(n=length(x))
exp.model <- lm(log(y)~x)
predictions <- predict(exp.model, interval="confidence")
df <-  data.frame(x,y,exp(predictions))
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
     geom_point() + 
     geom_smooth(aes(y=fit, ymin=lwr, ymax=upr), stat="identity")
print(p)
```

and I get the fitted exponential model with the confidence bands, but I get the warning

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: ymin, ymax
```

My question is how can avoid this warning?

Comment: You already have a model, use `geom_ribbon` for the confidence interval and `geom_line` for the fitted values, not `geom_smooth`. `geom_smooth` is used when you want `ggplot` to fit a model, (a loess or GAM by default).

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. But `geom_smoth` plots the right confidence bands despite it complains about the unknown aesthetics ymin and ymax.

Comment: Well, it seems that `geom_smooth` is passing those aesthetics on successfully to `geom_ribbon`, despite the warning. So I think your options are (a) ignore the warning, (b) wrap your `geom_smooth` call in `suppressWarnings()`, or (c) use `geom_ribbon` and `geom_line` instead of `geom_smooth`.